# DataGrid per row converter

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, converters

I have an ObservableCollection that I want to display in a DataGrid.
The collection contains objects that represent intervals (Properties Name(string), Min(double) and Max(double)).
The Min and Max could be of different units (e.g. mm or %), so I would like to use different converters (e.g. to convert to % and limit the value to 100) or stringformats (e.g. to display 2 decimal places or none at all).

Is it possible to use different converters or stringformats per row in a datagrid?

Regards,

tabina

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use one `Converter`, and use the `ConverterParameter` to indicate the useage. Your bindings might look something like this:

```
"{Binding Path=Min, Converter={StaticResource 
         IntervalStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Percent}"
```

Comment: Is it possible to do row-wise binding? I thought I could only do binding within the different datagridcolumns.

Comment: Row-wide binding is a different question, but basically you would use a DataGridTextColumn (or any other column in fact) and set the Binding like this Binding="{Binding}" which gives you the whole row

Comment: My data grid contains one column for the name and one for min and one for max. I would like to be able to set different units/converters in different rows, not in different columns (so I would need to set different ConverterParameters for each row).

Comment: Would it be possible to solve my problem with an ItemTemplateSelector?

Comment: Whatever logic you would have put into your templateselector, just put the same logic in your converter. an itemtemplateselector is overkill for this problem IMO

Comment: If I use Binding="{Binding}" as you suggested, I get the whole row and in my converter I could check a parameter of the row to determine the right conversion. For one way binding, this is all rigth. But how do I know which row I am editing inside the ConvertBack method?

Comment: don't implement the convertback as you dont need it